# Cannot Access Django Object After Creating it

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm having difficulty running a function with the following code. It works when I run these lines individually in shell, but in the function 500s and I cannot access the object I just created.

```
order = Order.objects.create(
                    user=user,
                    date_created=datetime.datetime.now(),
                )
print(order.id) #works fine and displays the new id
print(Order.objects.get(id=order.id)) # 500s and cannot find the object
```

Comment: If you filter by pk instead of id, does it still fail?

Comment: yeah, it still fails

Comment: Can you post your model code?

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue. Not sure if it can help, just give a possible reason.
I used a Database router to route write/read request to master/slave db respectively. In one trancaction, the codes writes to master db, but query from slave db before commit, so it can't get data.